# Change column class of df in R

Tags: r

I started with an empty `df`.

```
 > df <- data.frame("coeff" = numeric(), "value" = numeric(), "Type" = character())
```

Now I added a few rows to this `df` in the following way.

```
> df<- rbind(df,c(0.05,sum(main$c1), "BaseLine"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
```

Note: `main` is another `df`, sum of col `c1` need is added here. (nothing to worry about procedure up to this point). With this method, I added some rows to `df`. Since the last field in this code is `character`, `rbind` converted all columns into `character`.

I have two questions.

1. Is there a way around to use `rind` where it does not follow the `hierarchy: raw < logical < integer < double < complex < character < list`  as described in `rbind help`?
2. Is there a way to convert all numeric class to character and retain values in character class without insertion of `NAs`?
   for eg. when using:
   `> sapply(df, as.numeric)` 
   the values in column `Type` in the `df` changed to `NAs`.

I am looking for some function which would convert character fields containing numbers to numeric while leaving the character fields containing characters as it is.

> I don't want to use:
>   df$coeff <- as.numeric(df$coeff)
>   df$value <- as.numeric(df$value)
>   because I have many columns and the number of columns changes everytime I read the input from a `shapefile`.

Comment: what you want is a function which converts any column with characters into `as.character` and any column with numerals into `as.numeric` right?

Comment: @RanaUsman yes.. but avoiding the use of manual functions to reduce time lag

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `c(0.05,sum(main$c1), "BaseLine")` returns `character` vector.

Try:

```
df <- data.frame("coeff" = numeric(), "value" = numeric(), "Type" = character(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df <- rbind.data.frame(df,cbind.data.frame(0.05, 100, "BaseLine", stringsAsFactors = FALSE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
> str(df)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ 0.05      : num 0.05
 $ 100       : num 100
 $ "BaseLine": chr "BaseLine"
```

Comment: Yes. This looks great. But this gives rise to another problem. Try running the second line of code another time, with values "0.1", "100","BaseLine". Of course I can always use this code after first rbind 
 `colnames(df) <- c("coeff","value","Type") `    and then
`df <- rbind.data.frame(df,cbind.data.frame(coeff = 0.1, value = 100, Type = "BaseLine", stringsAsFactors = FALSE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE )` But is there a solution to preserving col names as well ?

Comment: The only solution I came across are similar to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231540/r-losing-column-names-when-adding-rows-to-an-empty-data-frame/41609844