# Append row in data.frame using list of variable with same name of columns - R Language

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

dears!

Summarizing my problem in a small example...

I want to append a row in data.frame using a list of variables with the same name of the data.frame columns, like this:

```
#createing a blank data.frame
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=3, nrow=0))
#naming the header    
head <- c("col1", "col2", "col3")
# assigning header to data.frame    
colnames(df) <- head
# creating three variables with the same name of header
col1 <- 1
col2 <- 2
col3 <- 3
#appending the row
rbind(df, list(col1, col2, col3))
```

The code runs, but the df continues blank. I would like a result like this for df:

```
col1    col2   col3
   1       2      3
```

Help me with this rbind.

Comment: Hi, you can try `df <- data.frame(col1,col2,col3)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `names()` function, you can rename the columns in R

```
#createing a blank data.frame
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=3, nrow=0))
#naming the header    
head <- c("col1", "col2", "col3")
# assigning header to data.frame    
colnames(df) <- head
# creating three variables with the same name of header
col1 <- 1
col2 <- 2
col3 <- 3
#appending the row
df2 <- rbind(df, list(col1, col2, col3))

names(df2) <- c("col1", "col2", "col3")

df2
```

produces the output below

```
  col1 col2 col3
     1    2    3
```

Comment: I've just tried. I came here to erase the question and I read your comment.

My mind was very tired, and I didn't see this idiot mistake.
By the way, THANK YOU!

Comment: If you feel I have answered your question, don't erase it and please feel free to grant me an answer credit

Comment: The reason behind the loss of column names has perhaps already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231540/r-losing-column-names-when-adding-rows-to-an-empty-data-frame)